# Will the auth endpoint change for enterprise box account?

Tags: box-api

As I understand enterprise accounts can have a custom subdomain like "manish.box.com". So in such case do we make the authentication call to "https://manish.box.com/api/oauth2/authorize" instead of "https://app.box.com/api/oauth2/authorize"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you'll continue to use the app.box.com endpoint for authorization.